# Can we have relationships in a SOSL Query

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I want to use SOSL to get relationship values?

```
List<List<SObject>> searchList = [FIND :mySearchText IN ALL FIELDS 
                              RETURNING 
                                 Account (id, name,phone, BillingStreet,BillingCity,BillingState, ownerID.Alias,ownerID.MobilePhone )];
```

I am getting an error

```
Save error: Didn't understand relationship 'ownerID' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the  describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Is there something i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the relationship, but you need to use `Owner.UserField` rather than `OwnerId.UserField`.

This should work for you:

```
List<List<Account>> searchList = [FIND 'test' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING 
    Account (id, name, phone, BillingStreet, BillingCity, BillingState, 
    OwnerId, Owner.Alias, Owner.MobilePhone)];

system.debug(searchList[0][0].Owner.Alias);
system.debug(searchList[0][0].Owner.MobilePhone);
```

Comment: Hi @MattK, I was trying something like this but it didn't worked. Plz help. My objective is to get Account Name.                         `find {go*} in Name fields returning Contact(Id, Name, Account.Name, Email), Lead(Id, Name, Company, Email)`

Comment: Hi @surajs21, please submit your question and query example in a new question for the best response. You may also want to check out the [Salesforce Stack Exchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/).